# undefined reference to `function' in only 1 file c,

Tags: c, ld

i have a c file named main.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
extern int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[]);
void start(){
    ...;
    int return_code = main(argc, argv, envp);

    exit(return_code);
}
```

you can see I declared main but when using ld to link it:

```
$ (use ld to link, I didn't write it down because it's quite verbose and irrelevant)
ld: bin/test.o: in function `start':
/home/user/Desktop/test/test.c:28: undefined reference to `main'
make: *** [Makefile:49: link] Error 1
```

so what should i do (sorry if this is a simple question for you)

Comment: 1) Joshua is correct: you shouldn't try using ld directly.  Among other things, you'll probably miss the (essential!) C runtime library and C startup object. 2) More importantly: `extern int main()` *DOESN'T DEFIINE MAIN()*!  It merely [declares](https://pediaa.com/what-is-the-difference-between-declaration-and-definition-in-c) that some function "main()" should exist "somewhere".

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C you have to define a main function that will be called automatically by your program, this is the base of your code.

I saw that you include "stdio.h" which is a library allowing to have access to some function like for example in my program the function "printf".
If you don't need it then don't include it :)

For example here is how to make your first program with a main function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    
    ... // Your code

    printf("Hello world"); // Just print on your terminal this string
    return (0); // 0 is the default return code if there is no errors 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, invoking `ld` yourself is being a glutton for punishment. Use your `C` compiler to link until proven otherwise.

`gcc -o bin/test bin/test.o` will link a C program for you.

It looks like you tried to "fix" it by providing `_start` yourself. You can't (in C). `_start` is not a function.

Comment: Reference for "_start is not a function"? AFAIK _start is a function defined by the C runtime.

Comment: It's a link/load location.  It can be jumped to or called.

Comment: @mnistic: Source: have coded in in assembly on the platform and written _start. It's not a function; the entry point is entered with a different idea of what's on the stack than the platform calling convention.

Comment: @Joshua what is your reference for that claim? I've always seen it referred to as a function, like here: https://wiki.osdev.org/Creating_a_C_Library

Comment: @mnistic: Did you read crt0.s on that wiki page? It has no `ret` nor can it have a `ret` ergo it is not a function. Another source here: http://asm.sourceforge.net/asmutils.html careful reading of the code will reveal in 32 bit that the first thing on the stack is `argc`, not a return address. It's not a function. I am one of the developers of asmutils.

Comment: @Joshua did you read the text above and below crt0.s on that wiki page? They are calling it a function. Just like the Linux source code is full of references to _start as a function (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/5bfc75d92efd494db37f5c4c173d3639d4772966/arch/arm/boot/bootp/init.S#L17)

Comment: Can you provide an authoritative reference for why _start is not a function?

Comment: @mnistic: That link goes into arm bootloader code. It makes no sense in this discussion.

Comment: Downvote until you can provide a reference. Making claims contrary to the content on established sources like OSDev is just going to confuse people.

Comment: @mnistic: Here's your source. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/kernel/process_64.c#L505 Since there's no return address it is a label not a function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242242/discussion-between-joshua-and-mnistic).